# Transliterate accented letters in C

Tags: c, unicode, encoding, iconv

Is it possible to transliterate accents **only** using iconv?

```
iconv_t iconv = iconv_open("ASCII//TRANSLIT", "utf-8");
```

For example I want to transliterate (Spanish) `á, é, í, ó` to `a, e, i, o`, but I need to keep `ñ`. Maybe is there a way to set skipped letters in iconv?

I know that I can use simple replacement, but first I want to know if there are any better solutions.

Comment: iconv doesn't have options to skip a specific character. What is the purpose of stripping all accents, but leaving ñ? Also what is your input encoding, what is your desired output encoding?

Comment: @Gnqz Both input and output encodings are UTF-8. ñ is an actual letter, not the accented one.

Comment: UTF8 covers quite a bit of symbols: from latin to cyrilic, how should cyrilic or greec symbols be handled?

Comment: I do not consider those. I don't expect those in my string.

Comment: You expect only Latin1 as input?

Comment: Exactly, only Latin1

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? You'll end up changing the meaning of words. E.g., "Mi papá tiene 50 años" = "My father is 50 years old"; "Mi papa tiene 50 anos" = "My potato has 50 anuses".

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: various online translators, including Google and Bing, translate "Mi papa tiene 50 anos" as "My father is 50 years old"

Comment: Then they are translating incorrectly (or more likely, trying to guess what the user really meant rather than what was actually typed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve the behaviour you've described in your question by simply utilizing the iconv tool since it doesn't provide an option for skipping a specific character. What you could do is create a lookup table (considering your input will be only in UTF8 Latin1).

The following piece of code could do the trick:

```
 char* stripAccents(char* text) {
    char *p = text;
    unsigned char c = 0; 
    const char* trans = "AAAAAAECEEEEIIIIDÑOOOOOx0UUUUYPsaaaaaaeceeeeiiiiOñooooo/0uuuuypy";
    while ( *(p) != '\0' ) 
    {
        c = *(p);
        if ( c >= 192 ) {
            *(p) = trans [ c - 192 ];
        }
        ++p; 
    }
    return text;
  }
```